# Compile man pages written in groff_man?

Tags: quickfix, makeprg

What would you reccommend as `makeprg` for compiling `nroff` documents (for **man pages**)? I currently have it set to `mandoc` because it works when I do it from the terminal: `mandoc foo.1`

When I run `:make`, it escapes to the terminal and the output stream produced appears to be fine. However the content loaded into the **quickfix window** is messed up and has weird characters:

```
||        sstt [--aaiivv] [--cc _c_l_a_s_s] [--ff _f_o_n_t] [--gg _g_e_o_m_e_t_r_y] [--nn _n_a_m_e] [--oo _i_o_f_i_l_e] [--TT
||        _t_i_t_l_e] [--tt _t_i_t_l_e] [--ll _l_i_n_e] [--ww _w_i_n_d_o_w_i_d] [[--ee] _c_o_m_m_a_n_d [_a_r_g_u_m_e_n_t_s...]]
|| 
||        sstt [--aaiivv] [--cc _c_l_a_s_s] [--ff _f_o_n_t] [--gg _g_e_o_m_e_t_r_y] [--nn _n_a_m_e] [--oo _i_o_f_i_l_e] [--TT
||        _t_i_t_l_e] [--tt _t_i_t_l_e] [--ww _w_i_n_d_o_w_i_d] -l _l_i_n_e [_s_t_t_y___a_r_g_s...]
|| 
|| DDEESSCCRRIIPPTTIIOONN
||        sstt is a simple terminal emulator.
```

I tried using the `-K` (encoding flag) with the available options like `utf-8`, etc. But it does not seem to work. Any thoughts? It would be really nice to load the compiled man page in a separate split like you can load man pages using the `ftplugin/man.vim` script and invoking `:Man ...` (with all the nice syntax highlighting)

On a related note, the quickfix window does not open automatically and I have the following autocommand set (works in all other cases)

```
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow
```

Comment: I don’t know what mandoc outputs, but if it’s terminal escape sequences, you’re kind of out of luck. I suspect just `man` will work, but you need an appropriate `errorformat`! For the separate window, maybe `new | read !mandoc # | set filetype=man`?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested, I found [a post](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-create-your-own-man-pages/7931/2) that addresses this issue: the suggested approach is to pipe the `mandoc` (or `groff`) output through `col -bx` to remove all terminal control characters, like so:

```
mandoc file.1 | col -bx | vim -
```

The setting would thus be :

```
set makeprg=mandoc\ -K\ utf-8\ -Tutf8\ %\ \\\|\ col\ -bx
```